# How to pass additional data to route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux, react-router-dom

I have a bunch of `react-router` routes that look like this:

```
<Route path="/users" component={UsersIndex} exact />
<Route path="/users/new" component={UsersNew} />
<Route path="/users/:id" component={UsersEdit} />
<Route path="/posts" component={PostsIndex} exact />
<Route path="/posts/new" component={PostsNew} />
<Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsEdit} />
<Route path="/blogs" component={BlogsIndex} exact />
<Route path="/blogs/new" component={BlogsNew} />
<Route path="/v/:id" component={BlogsEdit} />
```

I'm accessing route information via the `location` object using `withRouter`.  I would like to be able to know which "area" I'm in at any time.  I can do this currently by seeing if the route starts with a certain value (eg. "/users") but this seems hacky.  I'd like to be able to pass additional information - in this case, area - when I define each Route?  Or perhaps there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass additional props to a component, but you'll need to change your route definitions to use [`render`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) instead of `component`:

```
<Route path="/users" render={props => <UsersIndex {...props} area="users" />} exact />
<Route path="/posts" render={props => <PostsIndex {...props} area="posts" />} exact />
<Route path="/blogs" render={props => <BlogsIndex {...props} area="blogs" />} exact />
```